# ASP.NET Core OData 8.x How to implement /me alias for /users/<my_user_id>/

Tags: .net-core, odata

Hello trying to implement an OData alias like */me/calendarGroups* which would return the same, assuming my id=1, as */users/1/calendarGroups*. What I have thus far is a singleton MeController with for example this defined

```
    [EnableQuery]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<CalendarGroup>> GetCalendarGroups()
    {
        var user = dbContext.Users
            .Include(user => user.CalendarGroups)
            .SingleOrDefault(d => d.Id.Equals("1"));
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(user.CalendarGroups);
    }
```

and registered with

```
edmBuilder.Singleton<Me>("me");
```

Which seems to be working, but what I actually want is really just an alias, meaning not needing to define all properties of UsersController also on the MeController. How do people typically resolve this? The goal being obtaining the UserId through a JWT.